# Inject data from one type object to another

Tags: java, class, object

I have two different classes lets say:

```
public class Customer {
    public String Name;
    public String Surname;
}
```

And

```
public class CustomerExtended {
    public String Name;
    public String Surname;
    public int number;
}
```

Now lets say I have an array of Customers and I want to inject it into array of CustomerExtended. So the name and surname data would transfer. 
I know I can do it like this:

```
for (int i; i<CustomerArray.length; i++)
{
    CustomerExtended temp = new CustomerExtended();
    temp.Name = CustomerArray[i].Name;
    temp.Surname = CustomerArray[i].Surname;
    CustomerExtendedArray.add(temp);
}
```

But what I am asking is if there is simpler way since the structure is the same except the added field. I know there is a way in c# so I tought there should be a way in JAVA I just cannot find it. :/ Anyone knows the way and could show me an example?

Edit:
The above is just a quick example. Why I need this is because I have an Android application with a class that I use almost everywhere and I need to make an update for some special scenario. In this scenario I first have to populate a listview with local data and wait for data from a webservice that is same type but with 2 additional fields. Because of that I need to extend my local type and inject current data into it. So that after I can get data from webservice the types will match and I can just update the listview.

That why I am looking for the fastest and simplest way to move data.

Comment: Any reason `CustomerExtended` doesn't extend `Customer`?

Comment: Can you use `Java8` [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)??? Why is `android` tagged?

Comment: Additional information in my edit. Hope it is clear enough why I am trying to inject data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using inheritance:

```
public class Customer {
    public String Name;
    public String Surname;
}

public class CustomerExtended extends Customer {
    public int number;
}
```

And then create and populate a list of Customers

```
List<Customer> customerArray = new ArrayList<>();
Customer c = new Customer();
CustomerExtended d = new CustomerExtended();
customerArray.add(c);
customerArray.add(d);
```

You could then work with this list:

```
for(Customer customer:customerArray){
    if(customer instanceof Customer){
        Customer e = (Customer)customer;
        //Do your work here...
    }

    if(customer instanceof CustomerExtended){
        CustomerExtended f = (CustomerExtended)customer;
        //Access number:
        System.out.println(f.number);
    }
}
```

Note that you shouldn't let your field `Name` and `Surname` start with a capital letter and be public!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the library Apache Commons BeanUtils. In the class `BeanUtils` there is the following method (quoted from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html):

> static void   copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)
>
> Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for all cases where the property names are the same.

This works on beans, so you should add getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but you need to add `Gson` library for that. Your two classes are as follows in which i have add constructor to add few items:

```
public class Customer{
        public String Name;
        public String Surname;

        public Customer(String Name, String Surname){
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Surname = Surname;
        }
    }

    public class CustomerExtended{
        public String Name;
        public String Surname;
        public int number;
    }
```

Now you can convert the array of `customer` to `customerExtended` like as follows:

```
  //Adding data to array:
    Customer[] customers = new Customer[3];
            for(int i=0 ; i < customers.length ; i++){
                customers[i] = new Customer("Name"+i, "Surname"+i);
            }


//Here you can convert Customer object to CustomerExtended object
    try{
         JsonElement jsonElement = new Gson().toJsonTree(customers);
         CustomerExtended[] array = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, CustomerExtended[].class);
         Log.d("test", array.toString());
       }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

> Note: This can be done from AnyJson String to any json object which can be fetched from webservice contains some or all fields

Comment: This definetly looks promising since there is no need to make a loop and add one element at a time. Do you have any info about speed/performance of this approach?

Comment: Ya you dont need to use loop and for speed/performance thing i am using Google-gson library so obviously performance is good

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your scenario. But I see 2 options:

1. CustomerExtended to extend the Customer class (inherit it) and to add only the - http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java104/java104.html
   And you can have also a Constructor of CustomerExtended that to receive as a parameter Customer.
   Also consider making the fields protected (not public) and to have getters and setters for them
2. Another common approach for the cases when they need to be totally separated (which I don't think is your case) is to have an utility class that to convert the Customer into CustomerExtended

Kind Regards

P.S. I would also suggest you to check this one - https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html